# How to get NUnit information into CruiseControl.Net 1.5 after NCover has run NUnit?

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net, ncover

I've installed NCover 3.4 on my CruiseControl 1.5 and after some tinking, I've got the coverage reports shown in my cleanly installed CC.

I can't see the test results however (and never could after installing CC Net 1.5, as I recall 1.4 it 'just worked').

How do I get the unit test results from NCover displayed in CC.net? (NUnit details and NUnit timings)

Thanks,

Anders, Denmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - I found out myself.

I was including the wrong file under Publishers/Merge/Files.

Once corrected, it works as desired.